# SVN Tortoise connected to more different servers from one computer

Tags: tortoisesvn

Is it possible to connect to more different SVN servers using SVN Tortoise Client from one computer?

E.g. (*Folder 1* and *Folder 2* both on one PC.):

*Folder 1 - connected to SVN server X*

*Folder 2 - connected to SVN server Y*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check out working copies from as many SVN servers, repositories or individual paths as you wish. There is no persistent connection to the server with Subversion - the working copy has metadata that instructs the client *what* repository URL to connect to when it needs to communicate with the repository. But it works in a disconnected mode - unless you're performing an action that requires information from the repository, the client does not communicate with the server.